# MEF is not working in Visual Studio 2017 in my VSIX project

Tags: visual-studio-2017, mef, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

I am creating a new toolbar plugin and I am using MEF in my code. If re-create my code in a regular WPF application, MEF (Imports, Exports, ImportConstructor, etc) works fine. When I implement my code in my VSIX, my imports and exports don't work :-( I looked around and I do have the line:

```
 <Asset Type="Microsoft.VisualStudio.MefComponent" d:Source="Project" d:ProjectName="%CurrentProject%" Path="|%CurrentProject%|" />
```

in my vsixmanifest. Is there something I am missing to make MEF work within my VSIX project?

Thanks

Comment: It seems that it doesn't work for anything that is itself not a MEF created object. See: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6bbab2c4-e227-47c8-b964-038c8f7b9cbc/resolving-mef-imports-in-a-vspackage?forum=vsx